# how to gather the unique related rows in a neo4j cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have 3 posts, 1 of which has two comments. I need to retrieve the 3 post plus the 2 comments and the authors. Problem is cypher returns all the associated links. How can I get only the rows I need? When run this query I get 72 rows....I am only expecting 4 rows:

```
MATCH (p:Posts)
WITH p
MATCH(c:Comments)-[r:COMMENTED_ON]-()
WITH p, c 
MATCH (u)-[:MADE_A_POST]->()
WITH p,c,u
MATCH (n)-[:POSTED_COMMENT]-() 
RETURN {post:p,comments:c,author:u,commentator:n}
```

I am trying to ensure that each row only contain the properties related to that row. In this case I should have 4 rows...since one of the post has 2 comments. I looked at UNION, COLLECT and DISTINCT and none seems to be a good fit. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your query you are effectively doing the following:

- Match all posts
- Match all comments that have a COMMENTED_ON relationship
- MATCH all nodes that have a MADE_A_POST relationship
- MATCH all nodes that have POSTED_COMMENT relationship

As I don't have sight of your data model, I can only guess, but it looks like you're making no direct connection between posts with comments, and then finding the authors of those.

Taking a guess, I think your query should look like the following:

```
MATCH (p:Posts)
WITH p
MATCH (n)-[:POSTED_COMMENT]-(c:Comments)-[r:COMMENTED_ON]-(p)
MATCH (u)-[:MADE_A_POST]->(p)
RETURN {post:p,comments:c,author:u,commentator:n}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback...the problem is why you make a direct connection like you have the query skips those post without comments. In your query I would get 1 post with two comments.

Comment: The data model is what I indicated 3 post nodes, 2 comments node, both comments have a COMMENTED_ON relationship with only 1 posts and of course a 1 user node with POSTED_COMMENT, the same user node MADE_A_POST...in all you have six nodes and 7 relationship...keeping it simple

Comment: can you please post a picture of your data model?